# Move files via Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm looking for webpack plugin or other solution to `move` files from one folder to another on `afterEmit` phase.

There are several plugins that doesn't fit in my case.

- https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin
  Can `copy` but not actually `move`. Source files should be removed.
- https://github.com/gregnb/filemanager-webpack-plugin
  Can't move files via wildcard. It uses `node-mv` package under the hood. So I can't use following config:

```
...
move: [
          { source: './dest/assets/*.map', destination: './dest' },
]
...
```

Another downside of `filemanager-webpack-plugin` is it doesn't update webpack internal assets state. It means that moved files can't be served by webpack.

Is there are any other ready to go solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You can try building your own piece of code that does exactly what you need, using webpack [compiler hooks](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks). I know this is not a "ready to go solution" but sometimes searching for plugins takes more time than actually writing your own code, especially if it's a simple task.